# How can I make this python2 function that reads emails run in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I've been following the guide here on how to read emails in python

https://codehandbook.org/how-to-read-email-from-gmail-using-python/

```
import smtplib
import time
import imaplib
import email

ORG_EMAIL   = "@gmail.com"
FROM_EMAIL  = "mygmail" + ORG_EMAIL
FROM_PWD    = "mypassword"
SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT   = 993
def read_email_from_gmail():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
    mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
    mail.select('inbox')

    type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    mail_ids = data[0]

    id_list = mail_ids.split()   
    first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])


    for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id, -1):
        typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )

        for response_part in data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                email_subject = msg['subject']
                email_from = msg['from']
                print('From : ' + email_from + '\n')
                print('Subject : ' + email_subject + '\n')
```

This code was made for python2 and running it with python2 works perfectly, but I would like to work with python3 and so i tried to translate the code. Firstly, I changed all the instances of `print foobar` to `print(foobar)`.

However Im getting the error 'TypeError: can't concat bytes to int'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mymail.py", line 37, in <module>
    read_email_from_gmail()
  File "mymail.py", line 26, in read_email_from_gmail
    typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imaplib.py", line 518, in fetch
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, message_set, message_parts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imaplib.py", line 1180, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imaplib.py", line 945, in _command
    data = data + b' ' + arg
TypeError: can't concat bytes to int
```

I'm not too familiar with this error. But using the original code from the text in python2 works perfectly with no issues. I kind of understand the error it's saying it can't concatenate bytes with numerics. However Im not sure why this error would occur going from python2 to python3.

Comment: "I removed the while loop" — what `while` loop? There aren't any in your code or the linked example code. Also, please [edit] your question and show the converted code you're using _and_ add a complete traceback showing execution up to the point the `TypeError` occurs.

Comment: Sorry, im just so used to doing the While, try, except loop that I thought I saw 'while' even when it wasn't there. I'll make the neccesary edits right now.

Comment: The problem appears to be deep inside of `imaplib`'s internals—so no obvious fix is apparent to me. I suggest you take a look at another examples of using the library, such as those at [PYMOTW-3](https://pymotw.com/3/imaplib/index.html) website.